# Is there a way to suppress printing a specific reference in the bibliography using biblatex with biber backend

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, apa-style

I would like to print a reference in my text using `\fullcite{}`, and not have this entry printed in the bibliography.
I am using biblatex with a biber backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The first option is to use the `options` field with the `skipbib` option in the entry you want to exclude from the bibligoraphy:

```
@book{knuth:ct:a,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX book}},
  ...
  options      = {skipbib}
}
```

(2) The second option is to do the same thing but without touching the bibliographic data in the `.bib` file. This can be done through:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
   \step[fieldsource=entrykey,
    match=\regexp{knuth:ct:b},
    fieldset=options,
    fieldvalue={skipbib}]
     }
   }
 }
```

The following MWE combines the two solutions:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth:ct:a:skipbib,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX book}},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  options      = {skipbib}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
   \step[fieldsource=entrykey,
    match=\regexp{knuth:ct:b},
    fieldset=options,
    fieldvalue={skipbib}]
     }
   }
 }

\begin{document}

This entry will be printed in the bibliography:\\
\cite{knuth:ct:c}

This entry will be exclulded from the bibliography:\\
\fullcite{knuth:ct:a:skipbib}

This entry will be exclulded from the bibliography:\\
\fullcite{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!